# Android Emulator WebView - 'No Browser Detected' in Chrome Remote Devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I have an app I'm creating in Android Studio (windows 10) with a WebView.

At first I was emulating it on Nexus 5x API 23, and with this I could go into Chrome > Remote Devices, connect to my device, and it would see my app and I could debug the javascript of my app just like as if it was a website.

Now I'm using Nexus 5x API 26, and the device still shows up in remote devices, and when I open up a Chrome browser within the emulated device, the tabs are debuggable from my Windows Chrome, but my WebView app doesn't show up - it says 'No Browser Detected' for my app.

I'd really like to be able to use the higher version because the device I hope to support has advanced CSS features (`display: grid`) that I really like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the following property in the onCreate() implementation:

```
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```